# Mechanicalsoup Not Logging Me In

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to login to a site with mechanicalsoup, but when I submit the form, it keeps me on the same page. I have done a lot of researching for this and could not find an answer.

```
br.open(domain + action)
form = br.select_form()
user_info = getUserInfo()
br["ff_login_id"] = user_info["eid"]
br["ff_password"] = user_info["password"]
br["empl-login_submit"] = "SUBMITTED"
br.get_current_form().print_summary()
res = br.submit(form, domain)
print(res) #This is getting a response 200
```

Comment: Can you disclose which website you're trying to browse? Does the site use JavaScript? Does the website have an anti-bot policy (i.e. do the terms of service allow you to use a script to browse the website)?

Comment: The site does have a anti-bot policy, but I am setting the user-agent. I have successfully scraped this site using mechanize with python 2, but unfortunately mechanize does not support pythons 3.

Comment: I ended up ditching the MechanicalSoup and just used the requests library. It was a little less hand-holding, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Mechanize to do this in the past, then it should be possible with MechanicalSoup, unless the website has changed.

Depending on what `action` is, this could be an issue with the URL passed to `submit`. The preferred method to submit forms is:

```
res = br.submit_selected()
```

This will ensure that you are passing the correct URL to the `submit` function. Perhaps give that a try to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Actually, this fails (I tried this too), I ended up ditching the MechanicalSoup and just used the requests library. It was a little less hand-holding, but it got the job done.